# Qt Как добавить библиотеку CLucene в своюй проект?

Tags: c++, qt, include, lucene

Я скачал CLucene с офф. сайта:

```
http://clucene.sourceforge.net/
```

И не могу понять какие есть способы добавить библиотеку в свою программу. Я предполагаю, что нужно использовать include для того чтобы были найдены файлы .h и .cpp от CLucene, но я все равно не могу понять алгоритм подключения этой библиотеки.

Пробовал выполнить рекомендации по сборке. Но она для линукса, а у меня винда...

```
    Linux Build instructions
=======================================

If you downloaded CLucene as a tar ball you should be able to skip straight
to the section titled 'building', otherwise read the next section


Rebuilding the autobuild scripts
--------------------------------
If you made changes to the configure.ac or any of the Makefile.am 
files you will also need to run through this process.

Requirements:
GNU autotools is required. I have the following versions installed:
Autoconf 2.57
Automake 1.72
Libtool 1.5a

If you use significantly older versions, I can almost guarantee
issues.  This is because each of the autotools is constantly changing
with little regard to backward compatability or even compatiability
with the other autotools.

Run the autogen.sh file in the root directory of clucene to run the necessary commands.

Building

The following will get you building assuming that you have suffciently
recent buld tools installed.  
1.) unpack tarball 
2.) cd into clucene
3.) if you downloaded a tar version skip to 5
4.) run ./autogen.sh
5.) run ./configure
6.) run make
7.) things will churn for a very long time, the clucene library will
be built as well as the examples.
8.) check the src/demo, test and src directory

In src/demo you should see:
cl_demo

In test you should see
cl_test

In src you should see:
libclucene.so.0.0.0 libclucene.la libclucene.a 
and symbolic links to these files.

9.) If you want to run make install to copy the clucene files into the system 
    include and lib directories
10.) You may have to run
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/clucene/lib 

11.) run ./cl_test in the test directory and check that the tests all run

Alternative (faster) way of building:
-------------------------------------
This method does not create library files, so depending on your needs you may not
find this method useful.

* Do steps 1-5 of the previous build process.
* Change directory into src/
* run make monolithic
* Change directory into test/ (cd ../test/)
* run make monolithic
* You should see cl_test_monolithic in this directory
* run ./cl_test_monolithic and check that the tests all run
```

---

Подскажите как быть? Если кто использует CLucene подскажите как эту библиотеку можно подключить в Qt проект?

Comment: Эта рекомендация вполне работает на windows. Прежде чем подключать эту библиотеку вам стоит освоить работу с компилятором C++, средства сборки autotools и qt.

Comment: Только для исполнения скрипта configure нужно воспользоваться программой msys из состава mingw.