# Возможно ли установить и использовать autotools на WIndows?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, autotools

Появилась задача для сборки библиотеки clucene на С++ с офф. сайта:

```
http://clucene.sourceforge.net/
```

В инструкции сказано использовать систему сборки библиотеки - GNU autotools. Краткая инструкция:

```
Requirements:
GNU autotools is required. I have the following versions installed:
Autoconf 2.57
Automake 1.72
Libtool 1.5a

If you use significantly older versions, I can almost guarantee
issues.  This is because each of the autotools is constantly changing
with little regard to backward compatability or even compatiability
with the other autotools.

Run the autogen.sh file in the root directory of clucene to run the necessary commands.

Building

The following will get you building assuming that you have suffciently
recent buld tools installed.  
1.) unpack tarball 
2.) cd into clucene
3.) if you downloaded a tar version skip to 5
4.) run ./autogen.sh
5.) run ./configure
6.) run make
7.) things will churn for a very long time, the clucene library will
be built as well as the examples.
8.) check the src/demo, test and src directory
```

Полная инструкция есть инструкция есть здесь:

```
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328068/qt-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83-clucene-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%8e%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82?noredirect=1#comment2348000_1328068
```

Ранее не довелось работать с autotools, почитал и посмотрел об этой системе сборки, но вся документация сводиться в сторону Linux, а у меня Windows.

---

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно установить систему для сборки библиотек autotools под Windows? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ставьте [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) и можете следовать инструкции для Linux.

Comment: @zed - очень хорошая рекомендация, может, оформите как ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите MingW или Cygwin: http://cygwin.com/install.html

*Вы можете выбрать, какие пакеты устанавливать.*